# Trying to open a file into a specific tab

Tags: excel, vba

I'm trying to get a file to open into a specific tab but I'm struggling.  I know there's something wrong with the location. I've tried adding brackets and other formatting to fix the location but nothing's working.

```
strPath = "G:\Budgets and Financial\CLT Budget Templates\"
strFile = "Belle Grove Manor.xlsx"
strSheet = "Sheet1"
strRng = Range("E2").Address(2, 5, xlR1C1)
strRef = "'" & strPath & "[" & strFile & "]" & strSheet & "'!" & strRng
Workbooks.Open (strRef)
```

Comment: What are you trying to do? Open a file based on the contents of a cell in a closed workbook? Don't think that's possible.

Comment: Or @SJR trying to open a specific file and then activate/select a certain cell on a certain sheet?

Comment: @BigBen - yes possibly, but don't think that's possible either.

Comment: @SJR That's what I was hoping for. I'll try and find another way.  Thanks guys.

Comment: You can open the file and extract the value and then open the other file. If you turn off screenupdating it won't even be visible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Does this work?

```
Sub openWB()

    strPath = "G:\Budgets and Financial\CLT Budget Templates\"
    strFile = "Belle Grove Manor.xlsx"
    strSheet = "Sheet1"
    strRng = "E2"
    strRef = strPath & strFile

    Dim newWB As Workbook
    Set newWB = Workbooks.Open(strRef)
    newWB.Sheets(strSheet).Select
    newWB.Sheets(strSheet).Range(strRng ).Select

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's an additional answer that defends against the sheet being hidden.

```
 Sub OpenAndSheet()

        Dim strPath As String: strPath = "G:\Budgets and Financial\CLT Budget Templates\Belle Grove Manor.xlsx"""
        Dim strSheet As String: strSheet = "Sheet1"
        Dim strRng As String: strRng = "E2"

        Dim WBK As Workbook: Set WBK = Workbooks.Open(strRef)

        Dim WS As Worksheet: Set WS = WBK.Sheets(strSheet)

        With WS
            .Visible = xlSheetVisible
            .Activate
            .Range(strRng).Select
        End With

 End Sub
```